# Newly added row is not reflecting on UI instantly in SAP B1

Tags: sapb1

When I add new row into the database and call `loadfromdatasource` method, it is not reflecting. I need to re-log to check newly added row. How can I instantly refresh data in matrix?

Code:

```
oUserTable.Code = "Temp1";    oUserTable.UserFields.Fields.Item("U_barcode").Value = oEditTxt.String;    oUserTable.UserFields.Fields.Item("U_keyword").Value = oEditTxt1.String;    oUserTable.UserFields.Fields.Item("U_pdocentry").Value = DocEntry;    oUserTable.UserFields.Fields.Item("U_pobjtype").Value = "17";    int i = oUserTable.Add();  SAPbouiCOM.Form oForm = Application.SBO_Application.OpenForm(SAPbouiCOM.BoFormObjectEnum.fo_Order, "", DocEntry.ToString());    if (i != 0){    oApp.SetStatusBarMessage("Error" + oCompany.GetLastErrorDescription(), SAPbouiCOM.BoMessageTime.bmt_Medium, false); }else{    oApp.SetStatusBarMessage("Successfully inserted data" + oCompany.GetLastErrorDescription(), SAPbouiCOM.BoMessageTime.bmt_Medium, false); oMatrix.LoadFromDataSource();}}}
```

Comment: Show the code you have used so far.

Comment: Hi @KinyanjuiKamau,   I have added code in question.

Comment: Install B1 SDK if you don't have it. There is a sample under (my path, edit for yours) C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\SAP Business One SDK\Samples\COM UI\CSharp\06.UseMatrix. Follow the example.